# session logout button bootstrap

Tags: php, html, twitter-bootstrap

I have made a login form, where I also have sessions. That is working fine, and you can also see that I get more buttons visible, when I am logged in. I would like that my Login in the topright hand corner switch to the name of the user, and in the dropdown menu I get a red button where it says logout. I have been trying to do some of the coding I do with the buttons... Where I `<?php include 'buttons.php' ?>`. But I cannot get anything to work.

The logout button you see in the left side is working, so the question is more, how can I get it in the dropdown menu instead?

[image: Login]
[image: Logout]

header.php

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-default navbar-fixed-top topnav" role="navigation">
        <div class="container topnav">
            <!-- Brand and toggle get grouped for better mobile display -->
            <div class="navbar-header">
                <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#bs-example-navbar-collapse-1">
                    <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                </button>
                <a class="navbar-brand topnav" href="index.php">Logo</a>
            </div>
            <!-- Collect the nav links, forms, and other content for toggling -->
            <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="bs-example-navbar-collapse-1">
                <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
                    <li>
                        <a href="#about">About</a>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <a href="#services">Services</a>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <a href="#contact">Contact</a>
                    </li>
                    <?php include 'buttons.php' ?>

            <!-- Login Form -->
     <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
        <li class="dropdown">
          <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown"><b>Login</b> <span class="caret"></span></a>
            <ul id="login-dp" class="dropdown-menu">
                <li>
                     <div class="row">
                            <div class="col-md-12">
                                Login via
                                <div class="social-buttons">
                                    <a href="#" class="btn btn-fb"><i class="fa fa-facebook"></i> Facebook</a>
                                    <a href="#" class="btn btn-tw"><i class="fa fa-twitter"></i> Twitter</a>
                                </div>
                                or
                                 <form class="form" role="form" method="post" action="" accept-charset="UTF-8" id="login-nav">
                                        <div class="form-group">
                                             <label class="sr-only" for="exampleInputEmail2">Email address</label>
                                             <input type="email" name="username" class="form-control" id="exampleInputEmail2" placeholder="Email address" required>
                                        </div>
                                        <div class="form-group">
                                             <label class="sr-only" for="exampleInputPassword2">Password</label>
                                             <input type="password" name="password" class="form-control" id="exampleInputPassword2" placeholder="Password" required>
                                             <div class="help-block text-right"><a href="">Forget the password ?</a></div>
                                        </div>
                                        <div class="form-group">
                                             <button type="submit" name="submit" class="btn btn-primary btn-block">Sign in</button>
                                        </div>
                                        <div class="checkbox">
                                             <label>
                                             <input type="checkbox"> keep me logged-in
                                             </label>
                                        </div>
                                 </form>
                            </div>
                            <div class="bottom text-center">
                                New here ? <a href="join.php"><b>Join Us</b></a>
                            </div>
                     </div>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </li>
      </ul>
           <!-- /.Login Form -->
        </div>
        <!-- /.container -->
    </nav>
```

profile.php

```
<body>
    <?php require 'header.php' ?>
<br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br>
    <div id="container">
        <div class="topbar">
            <h4 class="hello">Hello, <em><?php echo $_SESSION['username'];?>!</em>
            <a href="logout.php" style="font-size:18px">Logout?</a>
        <a href="test.php">test</a></h4>
        </div>

    </div>
</body>
```

session.php:

```
<?php
    if( !isset( $_SESSION ) ) session_start();
    if( !isset( $_SESSION['username'] ) ) exit( header('Location: index.php') );
?>
```

Comment: Are you asking how to change the `<!-- Login Form --> ... <!-- /.Login Form -->` part in `header.php` depending on whether a user is logged in or not?

Comment: Thank you a lot for your answer. Maybe I was a little bit unclear. But yes that is what I am asking :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Would something like this work for you:

First, you copy your current login menu, and paste it directly below itself. You then put `<?php if ( user_is_logged_in() ) { ?>` above the first one, `<?php } else { ?>` between them, and `<?php } ?>` below the second one. Then you edit the first one to look like you want it to look if a user is logged in.

So the idea is this:

```
if ( user_is_logged_in() ) {
    // TODO: edit this copy
    ?> 
    LOGINFORM
    <? php
} else {
    ?>
    LOGINFORM
    <?php
}
```

If you use that inside HTML you need to wrap that in `<?php` and `?>`.

Here's a more detailed example of `header.php`:

```
....
<?php include 'buttons.php' ?>

<?php
if ( isset( $_SESSION['username'] ) ) // user is logged in
{
?>
   <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
      <li class="dropdown">
        <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">
          <b><?php echo $_SESSION['username'];?> </b> <span class="caret"></span>
        </a>
   ...
   </ul>

<?php
}
else // not logged in
{
?>
   <!-- Login Form -->
   <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
      <li class="dropdown">
        <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">
          <b>Login</b> <span class="caret"></span>
        </a>
   ...
   </ul>
   <!-- /.Login Form -->
<?php
}
?>
..rest of file
```

Comment: Thank you a lot for your answer again. It seems like some of it is working, but I have to dropdowns, so I have to implement the original dropdown box into your code right?

Comment: The basic idea is that you copy your current login menu, and paste it directly below itself. You then put `<?php if ( user_is_logged_in() ) { ?>` above the first one, `<?php } else { ?>` between them, and `<?php } ?>` below the second one. Then you edit the first one to look like you want it to look if a user is logged in. So yes, my answer isn't a "copy-paste" answer, and yet it is ;-)

Comment: It is totally working. Thank you so very much :) Now I can go to sleep, and think up I reached my goal today ... with a little help.. ;)

Comment: Thank you - I'm glad I could help. Goodnight!

Answer (score 1):

Simply write an if/else statement in the header.php:

```
<ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
  <li class="dropdown">

  <?php if(!empty($_SESSION['username']): ?>

    <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown"><b>Login</b> <span class="caret"></span></a> </div> 
    ....

  <?php else: ?>
    Whatever you want to display if user is not logged in... </div>
  <?php endif; ?>
```

Comment: Thank you a lot for your answer. Maybe I am just tired, or stupid... :-/ But is it possible for you to show what you would put in the div tags? My head is running around, how I should fit the code with my <ul id="login-dp" class="dropdown-menu">

Comment: Thank you a lot for your effort. I got it to work with Kenneys idea.